# Quero que a tag main não seja afetada pela margin

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar um segundo background no meu site usando a tag main, porem eu quera que o background ficasse junto ao texto nas laterais
*(sem esse espaço vazio da `margin`, no caso esse espaço em rosa na imagem abaixo)*

[[image: foto do site]
<sup>clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sLpO.png)

```css
h1 {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 350px;
  font-size: 28;
}

body {
  font-size: 18;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: url(fundo.jpg) center;
  color: white;
}

p {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-right: 250px;
}

h3 {
  margin-left: 600px;
}

main {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang='pt'>

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title> All the Boeings AvianAir </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boeing.css">
</head>


<body>
  <h1>
    All the Boeings and how to differentiate each one
  </h1>
  <h3>
    Boeing 707
    <img src="">
  </h3>
  <main>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id justo risus. Cras aliquam arcu non mi elementum, tristique aliquam lectus volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec non
      venenatis ex. Morbi pulvinar sit amet eros quis pharetra. Curabitur dictum faucibus lacus. Pellentesque lacus dui, tempus sit amet iaculis sed, rhoncus et quam. Suspendisse id neque eleifend, molestie neque in, laoreet lorem. Nunc eu lorem sit amet
      neque cursus finibus eget sit amet arcu. Maecenas at quam laoreet, convallis lorem blandit, efficitur enim.
    </p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você botou margin no seletor `p`. Ao invés de:

```css
p {
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 250px;
}
```

Substitua para:

```css
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: eu retirei assim como a outra resposta tambem fala, mas ai eu nao consigo deixar o texto no meio da tela como estava... teria como eu deixar o texto daquele jeito e ainda sim fazer com que o background fique do jeito que eu quero? https://imgur.com/a/GLFs26J (exemplo de como ficou)

Comment: Sim! Você teria que escrever dentro do bloco do seletor main: 
`display: block; /* o margin auto só funciona se o modo do display for block */ width: 400px; /*a largura que você deseja que texto ocupe*/ margin: auto; /* Para deixar no centro */`

Answer (score 0):

Experimente alterar o css do elemento `p` para:

```
p {
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-right: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O Problema aparentemente está na sua tag ***p*** que está causando este afastamento que você está dizendo.
Removendo a margin deste componente no CSS ele já se ajusta na tela inteira.

> Código CSS corrigido:

```css
h1 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 350px;
    font-size: 28;
}

body {
    font-size: 18;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: url(fundo.jpg) center;
    color: white;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
h3 {
    margin-left: 600px;
}

main {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: eu retirei assim como a outra resposta tambem fala, mas ai eu nao consigo deixar o texto no meio da tela como estava... teria como eu deixar o texto daquele jeito e ainda sim fazer com que o background fique do jeito que eu quero? https://imgur.com/a/GLFs26J (exemplo de como ficou)

Comment: Nesse caso você pode utilizar o Padding que é o espaçamento dentro do componente, sendo que o Margin é o espaçamento fora dele. Outra maneira de fazer seria incluir essa tag P dentro de outra, fazendo assim um background para ela.